# Executing multiple mapred jobs that are executed in a sequence with a delay

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I wanted to know if it was possible to execute/or submit a mapred job to be executed in the hadoop cluster after a given delay from the job before. To explain clearly, jobs are submitted in a sequence and jobs are submitted before the prior mapred job completed execution, Say jobs are submitted to the cluster every 30ms to 1s.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use [Oozie](https://oozie.apache.org/) it's made to order jobs. Most distributions of hadoop (HDP/CDP) usually have it already installed on the cluster. It basically does worklow managment for hadoop. (ie run this job, then that job, then *that* job.)

(Can be run like a [cron job but made to launch on the cluster](https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/6/6.3/topics/admin_oozie_cron.html))